# The "paragraphs_type" entity type did not specify a access handler

Tags: 8, paragraphs

When i try to access paragraph type page i get following error.

`Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException: The "paragraphs_type" entity type did not specify a access handler`

I am using Drupal 8.6.13. How can i resolve it?

Comment: Should a paragraph entity even have a view route?

Comment: @kevin I m seeing this error for first time, so I  have no clue.